# Do I need to respond to a text message asking for overtime?

Tags: overtime

I received a text message at 1am asking if I could come in tomorrow for some overtime. She sent this to **everyone** at work. Do I need to respond and say, sorry no? Or just leave it? Thanks!

Comment: There's no general answer to this - it depends almost entirely on your company dynamics and the expectations of whoever sent the text message, neither of which we know. Voting to close as "company specific".

Comment: The obvious solution in your case is to pretend you didn't see it, which isn't hard to argue consider the time it was sent. The broader question is as @PhilipKendall said, determined by the type of work you do and what your employer requires for your role. VTC.

Comment: Has your employer ever given you notice that you are expected to work on weekends? If not and you have other plans, let her know that you can't reschedule on such short notice.

Comment: If you don't want to do overtime, you can ignore it since it was sent at 1am, if you don't want to be seen as avoiding overtime. But if it was sent to everyone, the sender probably hopes that _some_ people will reply "yes" and there's not enough work for everyone anyway. If I found out at the last second that I need 3 people doing overtime, I'd send a message to 10 people and hope that 3 say "yes".

Comment: If you didn't respond, your boss should have assumed the answer was "no" by default if you're not actually contractually obliged to work this overtime at such short notice.

Answer (score 2):

Why not ask how it's paid? Then it's their turn again, and given the circumstances they probably won't just offer a measly amount. Then you can still decide and give a polite answer, perhaps something like: "I'm sorry, I had this weekend planned with my family already. It would be a huge disappointment for them if I cancelled it. Please, next time say something a little sooner."
Don't mention their offer again, it would be implicit it couldn't win you over.
But maybe they surprise you, and once you know what they pay, you do want to work on Sunday.
In case you really don't, you were still responsive, which should leave a good impression.

At least that's what I'd do in an average case. A lot depends on your normal salary, your work contract, your company, the number of employees, your position, if you really have a family to spend the weekend with, how often they ask for overtime, what the reason is for their request, and a couple of other things, of course. Adapt my suggestion accordingly.